# Possible Origin of "ergo"

Tags: etymology

Is it possible that the Latin conjunction "ergo" was derived from the dative singular of the Greek word "εργον", meaning task?

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"? Like, alternate reality possible, consistent with the evidence if we didn't know the answer possible, or a possibility that we should consider now possible?

Answer (score 6):

The Latin *ergo* is connected to words about proceeding directly:

> Equivalent to an adverbial derivation from *ēregō, presumably ex- +‎ regō, with sense similar to cognate pergō (“I proceed”), from Proto-Indo-European *h₃reǵ- (“to straighten; right”). See also ergā. Compare with the adverbial use of ē regiōne (“directly, against”), with the same elements. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ergo#Latin)

The Greek *ἔργον* is from words in precursor languages also meaning 'work':

> From Proto-Hellenic *wérgon, from Proto-Indo-European *wérǵom. Cognates include Old English weorc (English work), Avestan ‎ (varəzəm) (Persian وَرز‎ (varz)), and Old Armenian գործ (gorc). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%BF%CE%BD)

I'm no expert but since neither etymology is listed as especially speculative, it seems that the experts do not think there is a connection between the two.